# how to make google sheet as question for my job?

Tags: google-sheets

I made a google sheet and i want to make it as a question. I need this all the data in this sheet recorded in a new sheet after people answer it and I want the table empty for next user to answer the question. And where can i get the response?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you make this a Google form and bind it to a sheet to collect the answers?

Comment: I tried using adds-on form builder but that adds-on make a completely different form

Comment: I mean [https://forms.google.com](https://forms.google.com), you can build a form and send it to people, and automatically collect responses in a sheet when they respond.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is to make a copy for each person who is going to use it.
When you share your spreadsheet with them you change ending of your URL.

Istead of:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXhere is youd document ID XXXXXXXXXXXXX/edit#gid=1535248610

You send them
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXhere is youd document ID XXXXXXXXXXXXX/copy

This way everyone will fill the different copy of the table and have to later share it with you.

Different option is to use a script that copies content to the new file.
You also can use Google form for this job.

Comment: well, this form is for public so i don't know how much people will fill this form. can you teach me how to use google form for this job? i don't know how to use script

Comment: While this form is public then I don't advise to use scripts as they need to be security cleared on each computer that run them. This is not a Google Form teaching forum. Please try on youtube where you can find dozens tutorials like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtoOHhA3aPQ

Comment: You may consider creating a Google Forms, form results can be linked to a sheet and the form is empty each time a user opens it, unless you allow them to edit their answers.